# C++: ambigous function

Tags: c++, ambiguity

I almost don't know C++, but I need help to solve project build problem. When I make project, it gives me error which says that some functions are ambigous. I clearly understand what it's mean ["It means that there are other versions of the function that take different arguments or different numbers of arguments"](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3165/).But because of my few experience in C++, I don't know how to solve it. So that's why I'm asking for help here.

The error which I have is:

```
C:\opencv-build\modules\java\core.cpp:172:65: error: call of overloaded 'PCACompute(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, jint&)' is ambiguous
    C:\opencv-build\modules\java\core.cpp:172:65: note: candidates are:
    In file included from c:/opencv-git/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/converters.h:4:0,
                     from C:\opencv-build\modules\java\core.cpp:8:
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2383:19: note: void cv::PCACompute(cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray, int)
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2386:19: note: void cv::PCACompute(cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray, double)
    C:\opencv-build\modules\java\core.cpp: In function 'void Java_org_opencv_core_Algorithm_setInt_10(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jstring, jint)':
    C:\opencv-build\modules\java\core.cpp:6219:32: error: call of overloaded 'set(std::string&, jint&)' is ambiguous
    C:\opencv-build\modules\java\core.cpp:6219:32: note: candidates are:
    In file included from c:/opencv-git/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/converters.h:4:0,
                     from C:\opencv-build\modules\java\core.cpp:8:
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4328:29: note: void cv::Algorithm::set(const string&, int)
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4329:32: note: void cv::Algorithm::set(const string&, double)
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4330:30: note: void cv::Algorithm::set(const string&, bool)
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4331:32: note: void cv::Algorithm::set(const string&, const string&) <near match>
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4331:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'jint {aka long int}' to 'const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}'
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4332:29: note: void cv::Algorithm::set(const string&, const cv::Mat&) <near match>
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4332:29: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'jint {aka long int}' to 'const cv::Mat&'
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4334:35: note: void cv::Algorithm::set(const string&, const cv::Ptr<cv::Algorithm>&) <near match>
    c:/opencv-git/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4334:35: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'jint {aka long int}' to 'const cv::Ptr<cv::Algorithm>&'
```

If you need some more information/code, please tell and I'll update question with it.

Comment: From the first message, it looks like you have a type called `jint`, that can apparently be converted to other types like `int` and `double`.  You're trying to call a function with `jint` as the last argument... but there's no version of that function for `jint`.  So, the compiler is telling you that there's an `int` version and a `double` version... but it doesn't know which one of those two functions you want to call.

Comment: This C++ code is obviously not mine. So solution just is to comment those functions? But i don't think that compilation will be ok.

Comment: I doubt the answer would be to comment stuff out, but I'm not sure.  So, you don't know much about the code and are just looking to build it?  If so, I'd check with someone who specifically knows this code (looks like it might be from OpenCV, so maybe check to see if there's a Q&A board here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Comment: It can be bug of OpenCV version from the Git rep, becouse this error appears only in Windows, but on Linux doesn't. So I'm trying to solve it by myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jint` is a typedef to `long int` (see `'jint {aka long int}'` in the lower lines).  `long int` is a distinct type from `int` (even if they have the same representation) so the compiler can't decide between the overloads taking `int` and `double` in that parameter.

As you appear to be on Windows, `int` and `long int` have the same representation (since 64-bit Windows uses a [LLP64 data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)) so you can:

- configure the project that contains the definition of `jint` to use `int` instead of `long int`, or
- add overloads taking `long int` that forward to the `int` overload, or
- cast the `jint` argument to `int` everywhere it calls an ambiguous function

Comment: How can I do the first point? Can I do it via Eclipse CDT or it must to be done in make files somewhere?

Comment: @Andriy unlikely; `jint` is a JNI type so trying to change it is unlikely to work.

Comment: Whether `jint` is a typedef to `long` or to something else is likely to depend on the platform; at any rate, the Java documentation doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: FWIW: given that `jint` is imposed by the JVM (which isn't part of his project, and which he cannot change), and that it's not guaranteed to be any specific type, short of adding overloads for _all_ of the signed integral types, the third solution is about the only one which can be used.  Just don't forget the bounds checking when you convert to int.

Answer (score 2):

You must give the correct type of the last parameter in the method.

Let's say you call:

PCACompute(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, jint&) with last parameter being 5

and the compiler does not know what to choose between:

void cv::PCACompute(cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray, int)
void cv::PCACompute(cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray, double)

because 5 can be interpreted as an int or a double. 
You must explicitly convert the last parameter to (int) or (double), and then the compiler will make the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

The build errors shows the problem.

A call to PCACompute(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, jint&) is not supported since the only possible functions which has the same function name (and possible parameter types) are the functions listed below. It just means you are calling a function of same name with wrong parameter types.

```
void cv::PCACompute(cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray, int)
void cv::PCACompute(cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray, double)
```